# Connect QGIS to MSSQL view (i.e. not a table)

Tags: qgis, database, sql-server

I've got a MSSQL view containing data I want to show in QGIS. The view transforms a BLOB field  containing WKB that is in one of my tables into a SQL geometry, which QGIS will be able to display.

When I connect to a MSSQL source from in QGIS the views aren't showing up. Is there an easy way to get them appearing?

Btw, I'm running QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa on Windows 7.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Steve

Comment: Why are you storing WKB as a BLOB and not just geometry?

Comment: Can you also post the view definition.

Comment: @NathanW, we are storing as WKB because there are systems attaching to this database that use LINQ2SQL in .NET code, which doesn't support the geometry types natively. WKB is more flexible and readily stored/used. Kind of a legacy code issue I guess. 

In terms of the view definition, it goes something along the lines of: 

SELECT TheId, geometry::STGeomFromWKB(TheWKB, 0) AS TheGeom
FROM Data
WHERE TheWKB IS NOT NULL