# Viewing MSSQL data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server, well-known-binary

I am working with spatial data stored in an MSSQL 2012 database as varbinary. I am able to view the spatial data in SSMS with the following query:

```
SELECT geometry::STGeomFromWKB([column_name], 4955) FROM table_name;
```

How can I view this data in QGIS? I have successfully connected to the database in QGIS and have tried to run a similar spatialite sql query on the table as a virtual layer, but it does not work.

I have also tried to add the table to the geometry_columns table. QGIS will recognize it as a spatial layer once I drag the table in from the database, but nothing renders. It still shows up as a nonspatial table in the MSSQL connection.

A user with a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49602/connect-qgis-to-mssql-view-i-e-not-a-table) created a view in MSSQL, but reported that it could not be imported to QGIS.

In SSMS the records look like '0x001110310...'etc., and in QGIS they are all 'BLOB'.

Comment: Your view will need an OBJECTID built on the row_number() function. What type of spatial data is it - geometry or geography?

Comment: From what i understand the data is stored as varbinary instead of geometry or geography - the only way I can view the spatial results is using the query above. The data can also be viewed spatially in a GIS routing software that my company uses to connect to the database.

In the database schema the column type is varbinary.

Comment: Thank you @DPSSpatial .... I used the unique objectid field to create a view using the SSMS and it shows up in QGIS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a view in sql server using the following:

```
CREATE VIEW new_table 
AS 
SELECT ObjID, 
       geometry::STGeomFromWKB([column_name], 4955) AS geom 
FROM table_name
```

And it showed up in my MSSQL connection in QGIS as a spatial layer.

Comment: it worked?! can you see it on a map??

Comment: Yes, it worked but I just realized that I did not include the objectid in my answer. The actual query was:

CREATE VIEW new_table AS SELECT ObjID, geometry::STGeomFromWKB([column_name], 4955) AS geom FROM table_name;

I added that view to QGIS and it shows up on the map.

Comment: ok good stuff!!